# Auto creating instances of class

Tags: python

I'm trying to create instances of a class by loading a textfile and using some strings from that as input.

This is supposed to spit out all the scene headers from a film manuscript and create an instance of a Scene class for every time it reads a scene header that is characterized by starting with either INT or EXT.

While it does find all the scenes correctly, I am having trouble creating the actual instances.

**How do I make instances of Class in the create function, and then print them out ?**

```
class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self, name, isint, isday):
        self.name = name
        self.isint = bool(isint)
        self.isday = bool(isday)

    def create(self):
        with open('output.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
             for line in searchfile:
                if 'INT' in line or 'EXT' in line:
                    return Scene()
                if line.startswith(INT):
                    Scene.isint == True
                if line.endswith('NAT\n'):
                    Scene.isday == False

    def __repr__(self):
        print(self)
```

Comment: What is the name suppose to be from the output.txt?

Comment: The entire line in "from line in searchfile"

Comment: if you intend to make multiple `Scene` instances you should either construct a list of them in the `create` function and return the list at the end or better yet use a generator to `yield` the instances instead of returning a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function shouldn't be a method of `Scene`, since it doesn't actually do anything but create a bunch of objects. You can use generators to emit your `Scene` instances as you parse the file:

```
def read_scenes(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
        scene = Scene(None, None, None)

        for line in handle:
            if line.startswith('INT'):
                scene.isint = True

            if line.endswith('NAT\n'):
                scene.isday = False

            if 'INT' in line or 'EXT' in line:
                # Spit out the current scene
                yield scene

                # Create a new one
                scene = Scene(None, None, None)

for scene in read_scenes('output.txt'):
    print(scene)
```

---

**Original answer**

Your `create` function is an instance method, so it requires you create an instance of your class *first* and then call the `create` method. This is kind of backwards if you think about it, since your `create` method should not require an instance of a class, since it should be the one creating the instance.

The solution is to make your `create` method a [class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod). Instance methods take in an *instance* of your class as their first argument, while class methods take in the *class itself*, letting you create instance of your class using different functions.

```
class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self, name, isint, isday):
        self.name = name
        self.isint = bool(isint)
        self.isday = bool(isday)

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename, name):
        isint = None
        isday = None

        with open(filename, 'r') as searchfile:
             for line in searchfile:
                if 'INT' in line or 'EXT' in line:
                    return cls(name, isint, isday)

                if line.startswith(INT):
                    isint = True

                if line.endswith('NAT\n'):
                    isday = False
```

Since the function is a class method, you don't need an instance of your `Scene` class to call it:

```
scene = Scene.from_file('output.txt', 'The Name')
```

It's equivalent to doing something like:

```
name, isint, isday = parse_scene_file('output.txt')
scene = Scene(name, isint, isday)
```

Comment: This all makes sense in a beautiful way :D I do have one question. If I use Scene.from_file('output.txt', 'The Name'), then wouldn't I be creating just one instance with "The Name"?

Comment: @JamesKolber: Yes, when you execute `return cls(name, isint, isday)`.

Comment: but then how is this any different if it is only one instance?

Comment: @JamesKolber: Oh, I understand what you're doing.

Comment: what? I think your solution is great, but how do I instantiate the classmethod to create a lot of instances?

Comment: @JamesKolber: Ignore what I said earlier, I misunderstood your question. See my update.

Comment: awesome solution. Wouldn't this create a bunch of instances called "scene" though? How would I go about giving them each the name of the string itself?

Comment: @JamesKolber: I don't know what the file structure looks like, but giving each one a name shouldn't be any different from what you were doing before with `isint` and `isday`.